# Accessing returned data from jQuery load

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I'm working on a vue.js component and I've got this computed property:

```
 loading_asset_status(){
        var img = $("img.modal-main-image").attr('src', this.current_image.img_url)
            .on('load', function() {
               return (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0);
            });
        return img;
    }
```

The computed property needs to return true or false which is returned from on load function but the img variable contains jQuery DOM object instead of true or false as I wanted. So this does not work.

I also tried this:

```
loading_asset_status(){
        var status;
        var img = $("img.modal-main-image").attr('src', this.current_image.img_url)
            .on('load', function() {
                status = (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0);
            });
        return status;
    }
```

But this one returns undefined. Any ideas how to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not returning status, as this is async, you have returned even before code inside `.on` is still executing.

You can however set a data variable like this:

```
loading_asset_status(){
        var img = $("img.modal-main-image").attr('src', this.current_image.img_url)
            .on('load', () => {
                this.status = (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0);
            });
    }
```

Where status you will have to define in data part of the vue instance.

Comment: I don't really understand what should I do. Maybe I am very wrong with my approach with this thing. What I want achieve is facebook like image modal where user can browse gallery, comment photos etc. All of that is easy, but I could not find any other way of letting my component know if requested image was loaded. Then I just v-show my loading icon. Is there a better approach in Vue instead of jQuery?

Comment: @ElDanielo, As @Saurabh said ,`.on` function accept a `callback` function `on('load', function() {`. The problem is that `return status;` is execute before your `load` method and that's the reason you receive `undefined`.One of the solutions is to use a `callback` function like in my answer, or as said @Saurabh in his answer.

Comment: @ElDanielo With my approach, you can have a status [data](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data) variable, which can  be set false in the beginning and set to true inside your jquery. You can use this variable in your `v-if` for showing loading icon.

Answer (score 0):

The call of the load event function is asynchronous. it's for that the return value (status) is undefined.
A way to solve you problem is to have a callback function

```
loading_asset_status(Callback){
    var status;
    var lCallback = Callback;
    var img = $("img.modal-main-image").attr('src', this.current_image.img_url)
        .on('load', function() {
            status = (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0);
           lCallback (status)
         });
    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a `callback` function.

```
loading_asset_status(function(status){
    return status;
});
loading_asset_status(callback){
        var status;
        var img = $("img.modal-main-image").attr('src', this.current_image.img_url)
            .on('load', function(){
                status = (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0);
                callback(status);
        });
}
```